# Wordpress - Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in wp-includes\load.php on line 662

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem in wordpress site. I get an error:

```
      Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in wp-includes\load.php on line 662
```

and because of this i cannot access admin area.

on line 662 in load.php file is this:

```
  $_REQUEST = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST );
```

which is a part of wp function:

```
     function wp_magic_quotes() {
        // If already slashed, strip.
       if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
          $_GET    = stripslashes_deep( $_GET    );
          $_POST   = stripslashes_deep( $_POST   );
          $_COOKIE = stripslashes_deep( $_COOKIE );
       }

       // Escape with wpdb.
       $_GET    = add_magic_quotes( $_GET    );
       $_POST   = add_magic_quotes( $_POST   );
       $_COOKIE = add_magic_quotes( $_COOKIE );
       $_SERVER = add_magic_quotes( $_SERVER );

       // Force REQUEST to be GET + POST.
       $_REQUEST = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST );
     }
```

Has anyone ever encountered similar problem and maybe knows what can cause this.

I have tried to disable all the plugins and it didn't help

Thanks in advance for any help
Rafal

Comment: $_POST is not coming as an array and thats the problem, try to dump S_POST to check what it returns

Comment: yeah, it returns null, but why?

Comment: that you need to check with your code, why its returning null, try from the first line for S_POST

Comment: The problem was caused by local server. Restarting apache solved it.